# Ember.js Rendering template while waiting for data

Tags: ember.js

I'm using jQuery getJSON for fetching data in my ember.js app (ember 1.7.0).
And have a small problem with rendering template while loading data.

Here is my first approach:

```
Parivar.Router.reopen({
    rootURL: '/account/'
});

Parivar.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('orders', { path: '/orders' });
    this.route('order', {path: '/orders/:number'});
});

Parivar.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(){
        this.transitionTo('orders');
    }
});

Parivar.Order = Ember.Object.extend({});

Parivar.Order.reopenClass({
    findMine: function(params) {
        return $.getJSON('/api/orders/mine?page=' + params.page);
    },
    order: function(params) {
        return $.getJSON('/api/orders/' + params.number);
    }
});

Parivar.OrdersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        page: {
            refreshModel: true
        }
    },
    model: function(params) { return Parivar.Order.findMine(params); }
});

Parivar.OrderRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) { return Parivar.Order.order(params); }
});

Parivar.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    renderHeader: function() {
        return this.get('currentRouteName') === 'orders';
    }.property('currentRouteName')
});

Parivar.OrdersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    queryParams: ['page'],
    page: 1,
    needPaginate: function() {
        return this.get('model.pages') != 1;
    }.property('model.pages')
});

Parivar = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#ember_orders',
    LOG_TRANSITION: true,
    LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
    ready: function() {
        console.log("Ember.TEMPLATES: ", Ember.TEMPLATES);
    }
});
```

And i have needed templates (application, orders, order, header and loading)
In application.hbs:

```
{{#if renderHeader}}
    {{partial 'header'}}
{{/if}}
{{outlet}}
```

All works fine (and i got a nice loading template!), except rendering header template. It showing only after all data is loaded and loading template is gone. But i want to show header immediately after loading application.

My second approach was to use beforeModel hook. I tried to render header template to named outlet there. But i got and error saying that there are no outlet with name header. Maybe there is no outlets when code in beforeModel executed?

In my third try i changed findMine in Order class to this:

```
findMine: function(params) {
    var orders = Parivar.Order.create();
    Ember.$.getJSON('/api/orders/mine?page=' + params.page).then(function(result) {
        orders.setProperties(result);
    });
    return orders;
}
```

So, i have empty orders object returned to app immediately, and then populated with data.
All works fine, except i don't have my loading template rendered, and showing user "You have no orders" until data is populated in orders object. All this caused by returning empty orders object.

Here is the question: How can i render header template before data is loaded, while still have that awesome 'loading' template functionality?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know how loading substate works. For detail you can check http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Generally speaking, for a route which `beforeModel`, `model`, `afterModel` are not resolved immediately, Ember will try to find if there is a `loading` route in the same level. If the `loading` route exists Ember will enter that route until all model hooks are resolved. In your case if you want to show header before loading data, you need to put the header out of `orders` template.

There're several way to solve your problem.

### The 1st way - put header into application template

Does the header need to be shown for all pages? If so, you can put header in the `orders` route's upper level route's template, which is `application` template.

In `application.hbs`

```
{{partial 'header'}}
{{outlet}}
```

Then in `orders` route `model` hook you can return a promise, then a `loading` route will be triggered.

### The 2nd way - use nested routes

If your header is only rendered in `orders` route, you can load data in a sub-route. And `orders.index` route is a good place.

```
Parivar.Router.map(function() {
  // This will create index, loading, error sub-states under orders
  // Note the blank function is needed even in Ember 1.7.0
  this.resource('orders', function() {});
});

Parivar.OrdersIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Parivar.Order.findMine(params);
  }
});
```

And put header in the `orders.hbs`

```
{{#if renderHeader}}
  {{partial 'header'}}
{{/if}}
{{outlet}} {{! will render "orders.index" here }}
```

You also need to have a `orders/loading.hbs` to trigger the loading substate. Or you can overwrite route's `loading` action to implement your own loading logic.

A jsbin example can be found here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sawez/3/edit

### The 3rd way - load data in setupController and use PromiseProxyMixin

This is not a good way for your case so I don't say very detail thing. The idea is loading data in setupController hook and mixin `Em.PromiseProxyMixin` into your controller, then you can use `isFulfilled`, `isRejected` and `isPending` properties in yoru controller to render different things. For how to use `Em.PromiseProxyMixin` you can see [this API documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html)

Comment: **1st way** is exactly what i did in my first approach  **2nd way** tried it, but got same results as in 1st way  **3rd way** really not a good way. Ended with hard-readable code.       I made some investigation in ember app flow, and found that ember don't load all for application route and then all for orders route. Instead it load application model (beforeModel, model, afterModel), then orders model (same), and only after this, it load application controller and so on. So, this explains why my header template in "application" loads after model in "orders".

Comment: For 2nd way I forgot 2 things, in order to enter loading substate to "orders.index" you need to add "orders/loading.hbs", and in order to generate "orders.index" you need to pass a function as the second argument to "this.resource". I've build a simple jsbin as a demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sawez/3/edit